# In GAWK 5.0.1, how to gsub "/*" and "*/"?

Tags: awk

I want to replace the following characters in a string with gsub:

- "/*"
- "*/"

However, I have some difficulties.

According to [documentation on operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Operator-Details.html), "/" is not an operator. So replacing it is ok:

```
    q = "/*"
    gsub("/", "-replacement-", q)
    print q
```

Output
-replacement-*

However, "*" is. So we should escape it. But the following code does not give the output I was expecting.

```
q = "/*"
gsub("/\*", "-replacement-", q)
print q
```

Output:

```
awk: test.awk:4: warning: escape sequence `\*' treated as plain `*'
-replacement-*-replacement-
```

Expected output:

```
-replacement-
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: `gawk '{gsub(/\/\*/, "too", $0); gsub(/\*\//, "poo") }1' <<<'moofo/*oboofood*/'` though this is on Gawk 5.1.0

Comment: Traditionally I would expect strings in double quotes to be interpreted as literal strings but that does not seem to be how Gawk operates. I don't know if this is a bug or a feature.

Comment: This is documented in [Using Dynamic Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computed-Regexps.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been my experience that the special characters can be referenced when wrapped in a pair of square brackets, eg:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{q="/*"; gsub("/[*]", "-replacement-", q); print q}'
-replacement-
```

Or, we can use a regex:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{q="/*"; gsub(/\/\*/, "-replacement-", q); print q}'
-replacement-
```

**NOTE:** both were tested in `gawk 4.1.4` ([rextester / bash](https://rextester.com/l/bash_online_compiler)) and `gawk 5.2.1` (local cygwin env)

Comment: And it works also on GAWK 5.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

> What am I missing here ?

One `\` character

```
awk 'BEGIN{q = "/*";gsub("/\\*", "-replacement-", q);print q}' emptyfile
```

gives output

```
-replacement-
```

From [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computed-Regexps.html)

> To get a backslash into a regular expression inside a string, you have
> to type two backslashes.
>
> For example, `/\*/` is a regexp constant for a literal `‘*’`. Only one
> backslash is needed. To do the same thing with a string, you have to
> type `"\\*"`. The first backslash escapes the second one so that the
> string actually contains the two characters `‘\’` and `‘*’`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*